# android - available cloud based testing tools and suites

Tags: android, unit-testing, cloud, automated-tests, stack-trace

I was wondering if anyone in the stackoverflow community could point out some cloud based testing tools for android. I would like to be able to test my applications on real devices that I dont have access to and get the full logcat and other data associated with testing. I know there are a lot out there but I would like to hear other peoples experiences with them before I go spending any time or money on trying them out. A quick google search brings up testdroid.com but I have heard of countless others that I couldnt find in the top couple of pages.

Any comments on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to this website : http://testdroid.com/

Comment: almost a year late but hey Ill take it :)